# mysql search with two joins and a count

Tags: mysql, join, count

I am currently trying to write a general query which returns the content of 1 table and another joined table plus the count of resulting rows from a third table.

Now my description might seem abstract so I'll try to visualize it

Tables:

```
posts
|  ID  |  title  |  description |  creator_id  |
   1      Title1    Descr1             1
   2      Title2    Descr2             1

users
|  ID  |  name  |  avatar |
   1      User1    PATH

interactions
|  ID  |  type  |  target_id  |  identifier  |
   1      view       1             IP
   2      view       1             IP
```

Now what I am looking for is an output like this:

```
|  ID  |  title  |  description  |  name  |  avatar  |  view_count  |
   1      Title1    Descr1          User1    PATH           2
   2      Title2    Descr2          User1    PATH           0
```

My current query looks like following:

```
SELECT 
    posts.id, posts.title, posts.description,
    users.name, users.avatar,
    COUNT(interactions.id) AS view_count
FROM
    posts
LEFT JOIN
    users
    ON
        posts.creator_id = users.id
LEFT JOIN
    interactions
    ON
        posts.id = interactions.target_id
```

But only prints out the posts result which has an interaction like this:

```
|  ID  |  title  |  description  |  name  |  avatar  |  view_count  |
   1      Title1    Descr1          User1    PATH           2
```

How do I need to alter the query in order to also get the other rows which happen to not have any interactions yet?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/ Can you provide the sample data here in a fiddle?

Comment: @10086 The User2 was a typing error.

Comment: @noa-dev,  just added this "group by  posts.id" in your query then it will work perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply subquery third table to count entries:

```
SELECT 
    posts.id, posts.title, posts.description,
    users.name, users.avatar,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM interactions i WHERE i.target_id = posts.id) AS view_count
FROM
    posts
LEFT JOIN
    users
    ON
        posts.creator_id = users.id
```

This is also better for performance (no groups, no unoptimized joins)

Comment: Thank you all, for feedback. Glad to help you

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT P.ID
    , P.title
    , P.description
    , U.name
    , U.avatar
    , IFNULL(COUNT(I.ID), 0) AS view_count
    FROM posts P
    LEFT JOIN users U ON U.ID = P.creator_id
    LEFT JOIN interactions I ON I.target_id = P.ID
    GROUP BY P.ID
```

It seems like you missed the [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) clause. Without this, when you use an aggregate function like `COUNT`, the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) says:

> there is a single group and it is indeterminate
>   which name value to choose for the group

That's why your query only returned 1 row.

Comment: still only results with 1 row :(

Comment: That can't be. There must be something wrong with your data, or somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;)

```
select posts.id, posts.title, posts.description, users.name, users.avatar, coalesce(t3.view_count, 0) as view_count
from posts 
left join users on posts.creator_id = users.id
left join (
    select target_id, count(1) as view_count from interactions group by target_id
) t3 on posts.id = t3.target_id
```

[SQLFiddle HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/922eac/2)

Comment: This prints out the same posts row as often as many ineractions there are

Comment: @noa-dev Try it again please or check the sqlfiddle link.